# Computing Averages from columns and rows that have text and integers

Tags: python, csv, file, multiple-columns

I've never been more lost coding, I'll link the specifics but i have no clue how to take averages from specific columns or rows from a file.
So far I've been able to: Open the file, Split the columns, and assign grade values.
I'm struggling to : Average out specific values from the columns/rows, and to write that on a new file.
I know what i need to do but I don't know how.
any help would be super appreciated
[SPECIFIC DETAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv0yN.jpg)

```
file = input()      


with open(file) as f: 
    data = f.read()
    data = data.split("\t")
    for line in f:
        student_average = line.mean()
        if student_average >= 90:
            grade = "A"
        elif 80 <= student_average < 90:
            grade = "B"
        elif 70 <= student_average < 80:
            grade = "C"
        elif 60 <= student_average < 70:
            grade = "D"
        else:
            Grade = "F"
```

Comment: `elif 80 <= student_average < 90:` makes no sense - any thing that is smaller equal 80 will automatically be smaller 90 .... you probably ment to do `elif student_average >= 80:` as you are already sure its < 90 elsewise the FIRST condition would have met.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:  You are using a none existent `mean()` method.  You are trying to iterate through a file object.  And your numbers are string, they need to be converted to number datatype.

```
import statistics
data = '90.5\t80.1\t70.9'  # <--- assuming this is the data structure of your file
data = data.split("\t")
data = [float(d) for d in data]
avg = statistics.mean(data)
print('average:', avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if student_average >= 90:
>     grade = "A"  
> elif 80 <= student_average < 90:
>     grade = "B"
> ```

makes no sense ... you probably ment to do `elif student_average >= 80:` as you are already sure its `< 90` else wise `if student_average >= 90:` would have matched.

Also bad:

- no conversion from string to number
- no mean calculation
- exhausting the file by `data = f.read()` and then trying to do `for line in f:`
  etc.

Fix:

```
with open ("t.txt","w" ) as f:
    f.write("95\t95\t95\t95\t95\t95\n")   
    f.write("85\t85\t85\t85\t85\t85\n")   
    f.write("75\t75\t75\t75\t55\t65\n")   
    f.write("65\t65\t65\t65\t65\t65\n")   
    f.write("25\t35\t45\t55\t65\t75\n")   

def mean(itrable):
    return sum(itrable)/len(itrable)


with open("t.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:
        line = list(map(int,line.strip().split("\t")))
        student_average = mean(line)
        if student_average >= 90:
            grade = "A"
        elif student_average >= 80:  # only reached if not >= 90
            grade = "B"
        elif student_average >= 70:
            grade = "C"
        elif student_average >= 60:
            grade = "D"
        else:
            grade = "F"

        print(line, student_average, grade, sep=" ==> ")
```

Output:

```
[95, 95, 95, 95, 95, 95] ==> 95.0 ==> A
[85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85] ==> 85.0 ==> B
[75, 75, 75, 75, 55, 65] ==> 70.0 ==> C
[65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65] ==> 65.0 ==> D
[25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75] ==> 50.0 ==> F
```

Answer (score 0):

I wont do the whole thing, but you can split by lines first and split by tabs again after. You can add your own logic after...

```
#/usr/bin/python3

StudentsInfoFile = open("StudentsInfo.tsv")

data =  StudentsInfoFile.read().split("\n")

for item in data:
    if item:
        row = item.split("\t")
        print(row)
        first_name = row[0]
        last_name = row[1]
        exam1 = row[2]
        exam2 = row[3]
        print("first name : " + first_name)
        print("last name : " + last_name)
        print("first grade : " + exam1)
```